# How to show get response map to a side by side div using CSS in React

Tags: css

I am using axios router to get result from api, I need to show the response into a tile format like this

[image]

But am getting a results like this below.

My React and CSS code as below.

i need my 3rd child div be on the 2nd line, but the issue is the parent is exceeding the allowed max-width when child div has long length lines. and this disturbs another div next to parent div

```
  render() {
    return <div className="sdFoodScreenMain">

        { this.state.item.map(item =>
            <div className="sdFoodBoxes" key={item.id}>
                <p>{item.username}</p>
                <p>{item.name}</p>
            </div>
        )}

    </div>;
  }
}

export default SdFoodScreen;
```

CSS code :

```
.sdFoodScreenMain{
  float: left;
  max-width: 55%;
}

.sdFoodBoxes{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to style your component? Stackoverflow isn't a coding service show us what you tried.

Comment: Sorry @DennisVash, I have updated the css i did. The issue is the parent div is allowing the child div to allow three div in one line, without limiting on its max width

Comment: % widths are based on the width of the parent rather than the total width of the screen. If you want the widths based on the width of the screen, use vw instead.

Comment: @ZacharyHabe, i need my 3rd child div be on the 2nd line, but the issue is the parent is exceeding the allowed max-width when child div has long length lines. and this disturbs another div next to parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting sdFoodScreenMain to have flex and flex-wrap.

```
.sdFoodScreenMain{
  float: left;
  max-width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Edit: Here's how I would do it with flex. By changing max-wdith on the .sdFoodBoxes to flex-basis.

```
.sdFoodScreenMain{
  float: left;
  max-width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:  wrap;
}

.sdFoodBoxes{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cdghjn?file=style.css

Here's how I would do it with css grid:

They accomplish different things, so what you want in the end is up to you.

```
.sdFoodScreenMain{
  float: left;
  max-width: 55%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
}

.sdFoodBoxes{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nc88cy?file=style.css

Comment: This works but the issue is i get 5 divs in one row and it exceeds the max-width, I dont want to use overflow-y, but the contents should be aligned to next row, but its exceeding the max-width of the parent and disturbs the other div

Comment: If you want contents to align between rows, I'd suggest css grid since that has that capability.